# retrieving HREF link from google forms

Tags: google-apps-script

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
  var myemail = "duffysuchard@gmail.com"  // please, replace myemail by your email 
  try{
    var formResponse = e.response;//get the form response
    var editResponseUrl = formResponse.getEditResponseUrl(); //get the individual form url just in case the respondent needs to edit its anwers later
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();// get all item questions and anwers
    var itemResponse
    var title
    var response
    for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {    // iterate for all form items
      itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
      title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle().toUpperCase(); // get the question title. In our form can be EMAIL or NAME
      response =  itemResponse.getResponse().toString();  // get the corresponding answer
      if(title.indexOf("EMAIL", 0) != -1){   // if the title is "EMAIL"
        var email = response.toLowerCase();  // get it
      }
      else if (title.indexOf("NAME", 0) != -1){  // if the title is "NAME"
        var name = response.toLowerCase(); // get it
      }
    }
    var subject ="Confirmation";    // subject of the message you're assembling
    var message = "Dear " + name + ",\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
    message += "Thanks for answering our survey. \n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
    message += "Click on the link bellow to edit your previous answers:\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
    message += editResponseUrl + "\n\n"; // body of the message you're assembling
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {replyTo:myemail,cc:myemail}); // send the message
  }
  catch(e) {             // if something wrong happens 
    MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, "Error in Auto replying to contact form submission.", e.message); // tell me
  }
}
```

Comment: What type of problem? Do you have an error message? Do not get the URL? Do not send mail?

Comment: i do not get nothing, but an app script error    Cannot call method "getEditResponseUrl" of undefined

Comment: Remember that you can not test for this method from the code editor (easy way), so you have to fill the form and send it so that the trigger is activated.

Comment: i was trying to trigger on submit, what are you saying i have to pre-populate form then resend, this is the new script i am trying but still get same error

Comment: How are you testing this code?

Comment: iam using google spreadsheet script

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a `Spreadsheet form submit event` when in fact need a `Form submit event`.

In the documentation ([Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)), it is shown the structure of each event:

Spreadsheet Form Submit Events:

- values
- range
- namedValues

Form Submit Events:

- response

You need to create the script in the Form not in the Spreadsheet.